# bash array gives me unwanted prefix

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

```
declare -A script_input=([name]=input [input]=inputs [output]=inputs )
declare -A script_output=([name]=output [input]=outputs [output]=outputs )
declare -a scripts=(script_output script_input )
echo ${script_output[input]}
```

**The result is:**

> outputs

**I expect to get the similar result from the other code, but I do not**:

```
script=${scripts[0]}
echo ${script[input]}
```

**Now I get**

> script_output

I cannot figure out why!

Comment: `$script` is a simple string variable holding a string (that happens to be `script_output`).  You can't treat it as an array and expect it to work as you want.  I'm not sure whether indirection will work: `${!script[input]}` _(...after testing, it does not work...)_, but if it doesn't, you need to rethink your approach.  In the notation `${script[input]}`, `script` should be the name of an associative array, not of a variable holding the name of an associative array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the fact is that i need a for loop on it too!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you have any suggestion?

Comment: No; I don't have any suggestions on how else to do it.  I don't know of ways to do indirection on array names.  Someone else may be able to help you, but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the bash indirection syntax:

```
script=${scripts[0]}[input]
echo ${!script}
```

Note that the value of `script` is the complete "name" of the array element:

```
$ echo "$script"
script_output[input]
```

With bash v4.3, you can use a nameref to avoid this sort of fiddling around:

```
# Make script a nameref
declare -n script=${scripts[0]}
# Now you can use script as though it were the named array
echo "${script[input]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get around this with creative use of 'eval' to harvest values of an arbitrary hash referenced by another variable.

But if it were me, I'd be thinking about rewriting this in Perl or Python where I can have have hashes of hashes and other weird data structures.